# In Java, how do I refer explicitly to a static member of the class of `this`?

Tags: java, overriding, static-members

In Java, how do I refer explicitly to a static member of the class of `this`?

I want to refer explicitly to the static member for readability, but to not use a literal class name to respect subclasses overriding the value.

A contrived example:

```java
class Flying {
   static final String label = "A Flying Superhero";
   String exclamation() {
      return "Look! Up in the sky! It’s a bird! It’s a plane! It’s "+(WHAT GOES HERE?)+"!";
   }
}

class Superman extends Flying {
   static final String label = "Superman";
}
class Howard extends Flying {
   static final String label = "Howard the Duck";
}
```

Note that I want to avoid using `label` alone, because its meaning could be ambiguous; I want a reader to know immediately that it's a static member, as they would from `Flying.label`, but without naming the base class.

(In the case that inspired the question, the static member is also final, but I don't think that affects how you refer to it.)

---

**EDIT**:  Here's a possibly more compelling case.  I want to implement `main` in the superclass, and have it create and use an instance of the subclass that was invoked.

```java
class Super
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Super instance = new (?WHAT GOES HERE?)( /*...*/ );
      instance.use();
   }
}

class Sub extends Super {
   void use() {
      /* ... */
   }
}
```

When the jvm is started on `Sub`, I want it to use the same implementation of main, but use an instance of the subclass.

This case is different in that the context is static, and the static member to access is a constructor.

(This is coming up for a homework assignment in a graduate course in modeling & simulation; the superclass is a model, and different scenarios are implemented as subclasses.)

**To clairify the question**, I think three things are needed:

- Within an invocation of a static method, get the Class on which the method was invoked (I haven't found anything on this)
- Given a Class, access a static member of that class (possibly with `aClass.getDeclaredField`?)
- Given a Class, construct a new instance of that class (possibly with `aClass.getConstructors`?)

---

**Conclusion**

I hadn't realized I was trying to do something so contrary to the Java way until reading the answers.  Apparently I've gotten used to more dynamic languages.  (It seems wrong to feel like I've been spoiled by JavaScript.)

This architecture was largely motivated by the GUI provided by the framework I'm using, which gives you a class picker and then a UI to interact with an instance of the class you pick.  This makes the convenient way to work with different scenarios to have a class for each scenario.

For the original case restricted to accessing static members, for the time being it's good enough to use literal class names.

For the edited case involving instantiation, I'm leaving the instantiation in subclasses and passing instances to a method of the superclass, like this:

```java
class Model {
   public static void run( Model m ) {
      /* ... */
   }
}

class Scenario extends Model {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Model.run( new Scenario( /*...*/ ) );
   }
}
```

In the future, I'll try to avoid following the lead of some library into territory that conflicts with language features.

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done, AFKAI `static` variables and methods can't be overridden...pretty sure variables can't be overriden, use a method instead...

Comment: Just use the variable name.  It doesn't matter that it's static.  You'll still get the one you want.  And why is everyone answering a completely different question?

Comment: You can use `this.label` actually, but this is really a non-problem. Most IDEs will colour the variable differently if it's static. Or else you're trying to do something impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclasses do not inherit static members. In your new example, `main` can be referred to by Sub like `Sub.main(args);` but it always belongs to `Super`. You may even check the stack trace which will confirm it is invoked on `Super`.

- Within an invocation of a static method, get the Class on which the method was invoked (I haven't found anything on this)

This can't be done.

- Given a Class, access a static member of that class (possibly with `aClass.getDeclaredField`?)

This can be done but it's a totally cumbersome way to approach a problem that's extremely simple if you just use regular inheritance.

- Given a Class, construct a new instance of that class (possibly with `aClass.getConstructors`?)

This can be done and is useful from time to time. It is less useful now with Java 8 Supplier, for example `SomeClass::new`.

Static is the wrong way to approach this kind of problem in Java. Regular inheritance lets you do these things trivially.

```
class InterfacesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Arrays#asList
        List<Class<? extends Printer>> classes = Arrays.asList(
            FruitPrinter.class,
            TreePrinter.class
        );

        for(Class<? extends Printer> cls : classes) {
            try {
                Constructor<? extends Printer> ctor = cls.getDeclaredConstructor();
                Printer p = ctor.newInstance();
                p.print();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Printer {
    void print();
}

class FruitPrinter implements Printer {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Apple, Banana, Plum, Pear");
    }
}

class TreePrinter implements Printer {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Oak, Maple, Elm, Willow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't override variables, instead, you'll need to provide a method instead, for example...

```
class Flying {

    private final String label = "A Flying Superhero";

    String exclamation() {
        return "Look! Up in the sky! It’s a bird! It’s a plane! It’s " + getLabel() + "!";
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}

class Superman extends Flying {

    private final String label = "Superman";
    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

}

class Howard extends Flying {

    private final String label = "Howard the Duck";
    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like we posted almost identical answers :) I'll remove mine, but it would likely be better to keep the `label`s static; no sense in having every instance contain a reference to the class's label.

Comment: +1. Note that you are providing a non-static method here. You can't override static methods, either.

Comment: @arshajii That would come down semantics and the purpose of the design, not saying it's a bad idea, just saying...